# Docker - No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package

Tags: python, microsoft-azure, docker

Estou com problemas de importação do pacote azure-storage-blob em um container Apache-Airflow.

Minha imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu container em execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Instalei **azure-storage-blob** mas, ao executar um script, ocorre um erro **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package**.

```
airflow@707ab2142426:~$ python3 /usr/local/airflow/dags/azure.py
```

Estou tentando executar este script azure.py:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

print("oiii")
```

Então eu entro no bash do container em execução com o seguinte comando:

```
docker exec -it 707ab2142426 bash
```

E entro dentro do python, dentro do bash desse container em execução e faco a importação normalmente sem nenhum erro:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
```

Este é o print do bash do container após executar o script com a mensagem de erro e após importação manual do pacote dentro do python do container.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é meu Dockerfile

```
# Base Image
FROM python:3.8

LABEL maintainer="precredito"
# Arguments that can be set with docker build
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.12
ARG AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow

# Export the environment variable AIRFLOW_HOME where airflow will be installed
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Install dependencies and tools
RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get upgrade -yqq && \
    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \ 
    build-essential r-base \
    wget \
    libczmq-dev \
    curl \
    libssl-dev \
    git \
    inetutils-telnet \
    bind9utils freetds-dev \
    libkrb5-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libffi-dev libpq-dev \
    freetds-bin build-essential \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    apt-utils \
    rsync \
    zip \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    vim \
    locales \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    && apt-get clean


RUN apt-get update -y

#RUN pip install deployv==0.9.173
# RUN pip install build-essential==12.4ubuntu1
# RUN pip install install manpages-dev==5.09-2
RUN pip install psutil==5.7.3
RUN pip install python-dev-tools==2020.9.10


## Driver odbc 
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install unixodbc -y \
 && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y \
 && apt-get install unixodbc-bin -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-dev -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-bin -y \
 && apt-get install freetds-common -y \
 && apt-get install tdsodbc -y \
 && apt-get install libdbd-odbc-perl -y \
 && apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl -y \
 && apt-get install --reinstall build-essential -y

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Ubuntu 18.04
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

### fim da instalação do driver ODBC da Microsoft

RUN python3.8 -m pip install pyodbc==4.0.30


COPY ./requirements-python3.8.txt /requirements-python3.8.txt


# Upgrade pip
# Create airflow user 
# Install apache airflow with subpackages
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_HOME} airflow && \
    pip install apache-airflow[microsoft.azure,azure_blob_storage,azure_cosmos,azure_data_lake,all_dbs,crypto,celery,postgres,kubernetes,docker]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} --constraint /requirements-python3.8.txt
    


RUN python3.8 -m pip install azure-storage-blob --upgrade --force-reinstall
RUN python3.8 -m pip install azure-storage-blob --user

RUN python3.8 -m pip install azure-storage-blob --upgrade --force-reinstall


# Install R packages 
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('data.table')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('tidyverse',dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('caret',dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('readxl',dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('xgboost',dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"



# Copy the entrypoint.sh from host to container (at path AIRFLOW_HOME)
COPY ./entrypoint.sh ./entrypoint.sh
# COPY config/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg

# Set the entrypoint.sh file to be executable
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Set the owner of the files in AIRFLOW_HOME to the user airflow
RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Set the username to use
USER airflow

# Set workdir (it's like a cd inside the container)
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}

# Create the dags folder which will contain the DAGs
RUN mkdir dags

# Expose ports (just to indicate that this container needs to map port)
EXPOSE 8080

# Execute the entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Por que eu nao consigo importar um pacote que aparentemente é instalado sem nenhum erro?  Sou nova nisso.

Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Importei **os** e **uuid** antes e tudo funcionou!

Veja mais em [Micorsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python)

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
```